# how to assign a class name to any html tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is my div tag.

```
<div id="hero-container">
    //some code
</div>
```

I have no access to this main php file. but i have to assign it a class name. So what could be the solution to assign it a class name directly from anywhere?

Comment: If you can access page you can assign class name.

Comment: you can do this in your child page which is included in main.php

Comment: I dont have the original file. But I can upload my file. where I can write my code.

Comment: But your file will have some interaction with main.php ?

Comment: yes @Leopard I am adding my external stylesheet file. which will be linked to this main file

Comment: You can upload what file? Javascript file? PHP file included in main.php? What file do you have access to and how is it connected to main.php? :)

Comment: You *cannot* add class to an element with CSS. You will have to do it with javascript/HTML.

Comment: I am adding my own 2 files. 1) header.php and 2. style.css  so i can link style.css to main.php (its imaginary name, not actual file name. I dont know which file is it) through header.php

Comment: Then you can write the required javascript in `header.php` inside a `<script>` tag as @varlogtim suggests. If `header.php` comes before the `div` in HTML, run the code on `DOMLoad`

Comment: thank u so much @sabithpocker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128784/discussion-between-rasika-and-sabithpocker).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with JavaScript. Though, it needs to come after the div is loaded by the document.

```
<div id="hero-container">
//some code
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("hero-container").className = "A_class_name";
</script>
```

Comment: With just HTML, you simply modify the source to be, `<div id="hero-container" class="the-class-name-you-want">`

Comment: @Rasika if you cannot change the source file and don't want to use JS, then you would need to modify the CSS. Change `.classSelector {` line to `.classSelector, #hero-container {` to also apply the Style to that element.

Comment: Oh my god.. I didnt knw it. How simple is this... @varlogtim
But unfortunately I dont have that file Mr.

Comment: @Rasika Which files do you have access to?

Comment: I am adding my own 2 files. 1) header.php and 2. style.css so i can link style.css to main.php (its imaginary name, not actual file name. I dont know which file is it. ) through header.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128783/discussion-between-varlogtim-and-rasika).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign it a class name, `<div class="hero-container">` should do the trick. You can link the php script using the `<link>` tag.

*Edit:* To change the class dynamically while still using PHP, you can use:

```
<div id="hero-container" class="<?php if (condition) {echo 'aClassName'}?>"
```

Comment: can u explain some more @Mrmeguyme?

Comment: Sure. The `<div class="hero-container">` part adds the class to the div. If you wish to link it to a php script which is online, you can use `<link>` tag accordingly.

Comment: Is that what you meant??

Comment: Actually it was <div id="hero-container"> i want to add a class attribute dynamically into it.

Comment: in comment u have certain limits... post by editing the answer

Comment: @Mrmeguyme bro, u know what she will tell now... sorry Mr i dont have access to the html tag... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using jQuery `addClass`.

```
<div id="hero-container">
    //some code
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .yourClass{
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#hero-container" ).addClass( "yourClass" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: OP didn't list he/she was using jQuery

Comment: @KevinKloet But he used JavaScript, jQuery is Javascript library

Comment: @KevinKloet OP asked for suggestion to make it work. And user3099298 gave suggestion only, so if you have downvoted the answer take it back

Comment: I can use it only if I m not getting any css solution. I already have this code. Thanks a lot. @KevinKloet